# Why doesn't add_filter have the option to include a callback for each run?

Tags: php

The problem with `add_filter`, when dealing with a collection that keeps growing, as such:

```
add_filter( 'my_collection', function( $collection ) {
    return $collection[] = 'mellow';
});
```

And let's say, we have another run of the same thing but now we add `1` to the collection. So, let's do what you do 99% of the time in WordPress, play with arrays:

```
$collection = apply_filters( 'my_collection', [] );
$string = '';
foreach( $collection as $collection_item ) {
    $string += $collection_item;
}
```

And it'll break if the item is not of `string` type. In my opinion, when we talk of collections through filters, there should be a way to check what gets added to the filter.

As such, are there any considerations I'm missing for them not having this feature?

Filters are meant to play with **one value and keep changing it in the execution chain** so I understand that if something goes wrong alongside the chain (all the `add_filter`), it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to have this feature. If this is a problem you're having then you're using filters incorrectly.

Firstly, `$collection` is right there for you to check however you need to. If you need to see what the filtered collection contains, then just check the `$collection` variable passed to your callback. You don't need any other functionality.

But you shouldn't even need to do that. If you're using a filter with `add_filter()`, then it's your responsibility to know what types of values will be passed to the filter callback, and what value is expected at the other end, and it's the responsibility of whoever implements the filter with `apply_filters()` to document what these expectations are.

For example, if a developer (or yourself) provides the filter `my_collection` for you to add your own strings to a list of strings, then under no circumstances should you be adding anything other than a string, and you must return an array, because all other users of this filter and the return value expect an array of strings.

Filters are an API, and they should have defined and documented expectations for what goes in and out of them. Anything that deviates from this *should* throw an error.

In your example:

```
$collection = apply_filters( 'my_collection', [] );
$string = '';
foreach( $collection as $collection_item ) {
    $string += $collection_item;
}
```

If `$collection` is not an array of strings, then the filter has been used incorrectly and an error is the expected behaviour. If you provide this filter in your theme or plugin for other developers to use then it's important to document what is expected so that developers don't make this error.

Let's take a real example. The [`post_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) filter is a core WordPress filter for adding classes to a post. The filtered value is defined in the documentation like this:

> **$classes**
>  
>   *(string[])* An array of post class names.

That means that your callback function should expect that `$classes` is an array of strings, and that your callback must also return an array of strings. Anything else will break. There's no reason to check what values have been added to `$classes` because it should only even be an array of strings.